# Word/Office 365 customizable keyboard shortcut for specific text format

Tags: fonts, ms-word, office365, keyboard-shortcuts

When copying/pasting into a Word doc, the text format of the text (font/size/color) is pasted into the Word doc. Most of the time, a drop down pops up on the screen giving the user paste options -- keep source formatting, merge, etc.

This is a fine way to handle the problem of what to do with the conflicting formats.  Personally, I usually want to keep the source formatting and continue to type in the original format.  So the drop down and some re-positioning of the cursor *does* work, but there's one problem:

*Ain't **nobody** got time for that*.

I don't want to take my hands off the keyboard to fuss with the mouse!

Here is my ideal series of steps when I paste text on to the Word 365 screen:

- *cntrl+V*: the text gets pasted onto the screen with source formatting
- *space* / *enter* / *shift+enter* / *stuff like this*: gets the cursor to the spot to continue typing
- *keyboard shortcut*: puts the format back into a specific format that covers *anything* that you can do on the **Home -> Font** section of the ribbon -- font, size, color, whatever
- continue typing in this font, *fast* because I didn't take my hands off of the keyboard

I am aware that one can customize keyboard shortcuts in Word 365.  *File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon -> Keyboard Shortcuts Customize -> Home Tab* is really useful.  Heck, the whole Keyboard Shortcuts Customize is useful.

However, I can't find a way to configure a specific format and attach that specific format to a keyboard shortcut.  I have a feeling it isn't possible, but it'd be cool if it was.  Maybe a registry hack?  Or does Office has some sort of way to save a config file or something?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming, not end-user issues. Please post such thing on a site such as Super User.

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows**

Paste text (Ctrl+V) and then press Ctrl for paste options to appear and then press T for pasting the text with "Keep text only" paste option.

The result will be pasted text without formatting. No mouse needed :)
This works in older versions of MS Word too.

Or, you can simply set the keyboard shortcut for PasteTextOnly to Ctrl+Shift+V, then it works like before again.

That shortcut is a bit hidden though, so here's the steps how to get there:

File > Options > Customize Ribbon > Keyboard shortcuts: Customize...
Under Categories, select All Commands
Under Commands, look for PasteTextOnly
Set the keyboard shortcut for PasteTextOnly to Ctrl+Shift+V

See:
https://superuser.com/questions/1376470/what-is-the-keyboard-shortcut-for-pasting-without-formatting-in-ms-word

Comment: Please do not post end-user solutions on Stack Overflow, which is purely for programming issues. With 50+ reputation you could post a *comment* with the link to the already-existing answer on Super User, which is also where the question would belong. I recommend reading up in the site's [help] to understand what content is appropriate and on-topic before trying to contribute...